# ListView element contextual menu

Tags: android, listview, contextmenu, element

I have a ListView with some elements. I want to retrieve the id of element that I run the contextual menu for (by long-clicking). But following code:

```
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_adapter);

    /*non relevant code was omitted*/
    registerForContextMenu(this.getListView());

}

    @Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenuInfo info){

    Log.i("view", String.valueOf(v.findFocus().getId()) );

    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu,  v, info);
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_adapter_context_menu, menu);
}
```

returns always the same id, that is the id of ListView view and not ListView element id. I have tried some another options but coldn't find the solution. How to sort it out?

Comment: I think you need to implement onListItemClick because list views work with positions not ids

Comment: Try `registerForContextMenu()` on each element? It seems you're only registering the listview itself, not the children, so that is what is responding.

Comment: @Geobits Unfortunatelly, it does not work. Even if I try to register for each child, with parent ListView registered or without, it sees only parent in the former case or nothing in the latter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to get the list item id then use

```
lv.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                    int arg2, long arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return false;
            }
        });
```

Comment: if my answer is useful for you, give +1 vote my answer. :) always welcome my firend

Answer (score 0):

set onItemClickListener for listView. On the overriding method, obtain the view id

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long id) {

    String id = view.getId().toString();

    //open context menu now
    view.showContextMenu();
}
```

Note: Register context menu only once.

```
regsiterForContextMenu(listView);
```

Comment: Should probably use `onItemLongClickListener` instead.

Comment: normally context menu works on long click. You could possibly mock the same behavior by adding onItemLongClickListener for listView. Well, it all depends on how you want to implement!

Comment: @Renjith It works only if you firstly click on the item and then click-and-press to open contextual menu. 
Furthermore, I don't want to mix this two actions: clicking and long-clicking on an item. For example the item can be supposed to run subactivity on click and run contextual menu (i.e for changing label) on long-click.

Comment: @macbie nope, the code opens context menu on single click on the list view item. I am using the same in my application. Above all, it was one of my requirements. follow whichever suits your needs